# Discord.py throws error: to many arguments on purge()

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, discord.py

> Hi there, the following code is supposed to clear the channel. If the
> argument is a nomber, it is supposed to delete as many messages as
> specified. If the argument is all, it is supposed to delete all
> messages, and if you don't specifie an argument, it should delete 10
> messages as default.

```
 @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clear(ctx, amount=None):
        try:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount) + 1)
        except:
            if amount == 'all':
                await ctx.channel.purge()
                return
            await ctx.channel.purge(10)
```

> however, Im getting the following error, if i do !clear without an
> argument:

**Command raised an exception: TypeError: purge() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EFP6.jpg)

Comment: Which line was the error on?

Comment: it was in line 66

Comment: Can you please indicate in your code snippet which line is line 66? There are not 66 lines there so it is rather hard to tell

Comment: ou, sry, it is the last line

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but in line 5 of that snippet, you have `limit=int(amount) + 1` as your parameter. Shouldn't the last line also follow the same syntax, so like `await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10)`?

Comment: that was the fault, sry, should have seen this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`purge` uses keyword arguments, so you have to write `limit=10` instead of just `10`, see [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge)